# Hadoop pig FULL join

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am beginner with PIG. My problem is that after join:

```
ALLDATA1 = join dataA1 by subject FULL, dataT1 by subject;
ALLDATA2 = join ALLDATA1 by dataA1::subject FULL, dataR1 by subject;
```

I have 3 columns

```
ALLDATA1::dataA1::subject, 
ALLDATA1::dataT1::subject, 
dataR1::subject
```

and i need it all in one. Because when one ist empty other one is not. How can i Put all subjects in one column in join? Or hot to merge this column on condition: When ALLDATA1::dataA1::subject is empty use other one.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question with a good example? I there is some confusion over what do you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the 3 column output, you can use ternary operator (yes the operator from other conventional languages) to combine 3 columns to generate 1. Something like below:

```
ALLDATA1 = join dataA1 by subject FULL, dataT1 by subject;
ALLDATA2 = join ALLDATA1 by dataA1::subject FULL, dataR1 by subject;

ALLDATA3 = FOREACH ALLDATA2 
               GENERATE
                   ALLDATA1::dataA1::subject IS NOT NULL ?
                       ALLDATA1::dataA1::subject :
                       (ALLDATA1::dataT1::subject IS NOT NULL ? 
                            ALLDATA1::dataT1::subject : 
                            dataR1::subject
                       ) AS subjet;
```

Hope this helps.